# B+ Tree CPU search time

Tags: database, database-design

I was just wondering how would you calculate the worst case time for an unclustered and clustered b+ tree?

For example, say I had 1,000,000 records (1 row = 100 bytes), disk pages are 4000 bytes, a key was 20 bytes, and the access time of a page is 40ms. How would I calculate using these variables the unclustered and clustered b+ tree worse case time?

I know that to calculate the height/levels of a b+ tree you use the following (i think):

```
logF(keys)
```

where F = number of praches branches.

With the height, you can use it to calculate the final worst case time, but I don't know how to do that... I've tried searching around but all I could fine was times for average cases or examples that weren't very clear.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would say logF(keys) its the worst case to finding the page, but after that the worst case would be an unclustured index with all your rids pointing to different pages, wich mean

logF(keys) + N being N the number of rids in the index node.

so in the end it would be

H= height of the tree wich would be like 3 or 4.

H + N = 4 + (4000/20) = 204 I/Os

wich let say they are in memory and want to see the CPU time then it would be

CPU = 204*0.04 = 8.16 secs.  althought 40ms for moving a page in memory its quite a lot of time i think (for disk reading could make sense) but i think the calculations are fine.